# Separating form fields manually rather than using form_widget(form)

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to separate form fields and handle them manually ratger than using `form_widget(form)` however having difficulties.

This section works fine but I try to do same thing for the `form.new_password` and `form.new_password_confirmation` I get an error saying that `Method "form.new_password" for object .... doesn't exist in FOSUserBundle....` so on. The only thing I can use it for `form.plainPassword` which doesn't do the trick.

Anyone know how to separate the fields and display them?

**This is fine:**

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(form.current_password }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.current_password }}
        <p>{{ form_errors(form.current_password) }}</p></td>
</tr>
```

**Won't work:**

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(form.new_password }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.new_password }}
        <p>{{ form_errors(form.new_password) }}</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_label(form.new_password_confirmation }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.new_password_confirmation }}
        <p>{{ form_errors(form.new_password_confirmation) }}</p></td>
</tr>
```

**If I use `form.plainPassword` I get output like this:**

[image]

**IF IT HELPS:**

vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Type/ResettingFormType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password_confirmation'),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
}
```

vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Type/ChangePasswordFormType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if (class_exists('Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword')) {
        $constraint = new UserPassword();
    } else {
        // Symfony 2.1 support with the old constraint class
        $constraint = new OldUserPassword();
    }

    $builder->add('current_password', 'password', array(
        'label' => 'form.current_password',
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => $constraint,
    ));
    $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.new_password_confirmation'),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current password:

```
{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}
```

New password:

```
{{ form_widget(form.new.first) }}
```

Confirm new Password:

```
{{ form_widget(form.new.second) }}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't work. I get "Method 'new' for object .... does not exist in FOSUserBundle..." - I included my FOS Form Types above if it helps.

Comment: I just updated your code so it works fine now. Thanks +1